# Does an Database restore to a new Destination affect the original Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Today i recognized that last week I made an horrible mistake. I truncated a very important Table.
Good for me, i have a Backup-File before the truncation.

My Question now is:

Can i restore this Backup-File to a new Database without affecting the original (the one i truncated the table) Database or isn't this possible?

Software: SQL Management Studio 2016 and SQL Server 2016

Kind regards.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. You can restore the backup to a new database (with a different name) and select the missing data into the original database.

Comment: But has the original Database to be offline for this?
--> The Backup File is one week old.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be offline. That would kind of defeat the purpose wouldn't it?

Comment: Great that you have a backup. I have a feeling that what you have in place is a solid backup strategy. Unfortunately that is only the first step. What you need is a recovery strategy. Then you need to practice recovery.

Comment: Yes it would. But if i would restore the original database, nobody could work on it while the restore is running am i right? Or did i misunderstand something. I am newbie in SQL so sorry if my questions are stupid..

Comment: When you restore the backup, it has no effect whatsoever on the original database. You are really creating a new, separate database, so all functionality of the original database still works, nobody need even know you are restoring a database.

Comment: That would save my life though. Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i restore this Backup-File to a new Database without affecting the
>   original (the one i truncated the table) Database or isn't this
>   possible?

Yes you can as long as you are in fact restoring the backup to a new database.
The concern I have now is that *today* you realized you made a mistake **last week**. Once you restore you need to focus on copying/importing the data from the table prior to truncation to the table post truncation. All of this while ensuring you keep the rest of the data up to date (making sure you aren't overwriting.